# Solving for a variable that's an exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would you figure out this?

$x^y = z$

How do you find out $y$ if you know $x$ and $z$ ?

Comment: Clealry, not... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This [section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Definition) on wikipedia explains how.

You take the logarithm of both sides, 
$$
\begin{align*}
x^y=z &\implies \log{x^y}=\log{z}\\
&\implies y\log{x}=\log{z}\\
&\implies y=\frac{\log{z}}{\log{x}}=\log_x{z}.
\end{align*}
$$
The second and third implications follow by standard rules for logarithms.

Comment: X^Y=Z by definition is LogX^Z = Y (sorry, don't; know the latex codes)

Answer (score 5):

### Integers

Divide $z$ by $x$ until you get 1, how many times did it take?: $y$ times.

I'll give an example, $343 = 7^{something}$, but what value is "something"?

1. $\frac{343}{7} = 49$,
2. $\frac{49}7 = 7$,
3. $\frac77 = 1$

...so it's 3. Three separate divisions by 7 lead to one, so 7 x 7 x 7 = 343.

therefore $7^3 = 343$.

### Polynomials

If you suspect $q = p^k$ but don't know $k$ *or* $q$ you can easily find it out by taking the greatest common divisor of the derivative of $q$ with $q$.

### Reals and complex numbers

The logarithm function is defined by this equation